# Innermost value in html

Tags: javascript, html

Can you please let me know how to get the innermost node value in an html tag.

For example I have

```
<td id="cell3">
   <div>7</div>
</td>
```

I would like to get the value of 7 extracted from above

I only know about innerHTML that would give me

```
<div>7/div>
```

if I do

```
document.getElementById('cell3').innerHTML;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the [`textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the first child:

```
document.getElementById('cell3').children[0].textContent.trim(); // 7
```

or:

```
document.getElementById('cell3').firstElementChild.textContent.trim(); // 7
```

And if you know that `7` is the only text within the `td` element, then you can access the `textContent` property directly:

```
document.getElementById('cell3').textContent.trim();
```

---

<sub>I chained the `.trim()` method to remove whitespace.</sub>

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on possibly adding more nested tags within the `<td>` later, iterate through `<td>` children:

```
var currentNode = document.getElementById("cell3");
alert(currentNode.nodeName);
while(currentNode.firstElementChild){
    currentNode = currentNode.firstElementChild;
    alert(currentNode.nodeName);
}
var innermostText = currentNode.firstChild.textContent.trim();
alert(innermostText);
```

Alerts left in to show you how some of these methods work.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Beside, Josh's comment. You can do

```
document.getElementById('cell3').childNodes[0].innerHTML
```